# Why does Google script for each run differently for range in a row vs range in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, foreach

I am trying to create a list of tabs based on values in a row, as I have previously done with values in a column (The script here is an example test as I was trying to identify the issue, not the actual script used). However, the `forEach()` function is working differently and I do not understand why. Below I will append two sets of scripts and their results.

**For column**:

```
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,5,1);
  var STlist = [];

  range.getValues().forEach(function(x){
    Logger.log(x + " why");
    STlist.push(x);
  });

  Logger.log(STlist);  
}
```

**Output for column**

```
[20-02-28 12:10:58:012 HKT] z why
[20-02-28 12:10:58:018 HKT] a why
[20-02-28 12:10:58:021 HKT] b why
[20-02-28 12:10:58:023 HKT] c why
[20-02-28 12:10:58:026 HKT] d why
[20-02-28 12:10:58:029 HKT] [[z], [a], [b], [c], [d]]
```

**For Row**

```
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,5);
  var STlist = [];

  range.getValues().forEach(function(x){
    Logger.log(x + " why");
    STlist.push(x);
  });

  Logger.log(STlist);  
}
```

**Output for row**

```
[20-02-28 12:11:35:013 HKT] z,x,d,v,g why
[20-02-28 12:11:35:018 HKT] [[z, x, d, v, g]]
```

Would it be possible for the row format to work the same as the column format? As I was expecting to see the same results but I got different results.

Thank you

Comment: In one you have a 5-element array where each element is itself a 1-element array. In the other you have a 1-element array in which the element is a 5-element array. In both cases you received a multidimensional array.

Comment: but in case number 2, the why is only appended to the last element in the array, not every element.

Comment: That's because `+` operator implicitly converts the row array to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put in spreadsheet terms,  the values array always contain rows and each of the rows contain column elements. In both cases,

```
range.getValues().forEach(function(x){
```

The `x` will be a row. And row will be a array with column elements:

A1:A5: `[[z], [a], [b], [c], [d]]`
A1:E1: `[[z, x, d, v, g]]`

A1:A5 has 5 rows and each of those rows contain a column element. So, `forEach(row=>)` will iterate 5 rows. A1:E1 contain 1 row and therefore `forEach(row=>)` will iterate 1 row. To iterate the elements in each row, you'd need another for-loop:

```js
const arr1 = [["a1","b1"]];
const arr2 = [["a1"],["a2"]];
const arr3 = [["a1","b1"],
                   ["a2","b2"]];
const st = JSON.stringify
const loop_ = (arr) => 
  arr.forEach((row, i) => 
    row.forEach((colEl, j) => 
      console.info(`This array is ${st(arr)} 
            row is ${st(row)} 
            Current column is ${st(colEl)}
            col Element at index [${i},${j}] in this array is ${colEl}`)));

[arr1,arr2,arr3].forEach(loop_)
```

#### References:

- [Basic reading](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading)
- [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515924/)

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Comment: Hi, TheMaster, thank you for your explanation, now i understand:) Are you able to include some comments on how each line work? As i would really like to understand the purpose of each line of code, and i am not familiar with JSON.stringify and how the arrows work, are they the same as forEach?

Comment: @edmund JSON.stringify just converts the array to string. It's not needed. I used it to show the array as string in the console logs. `=>` is the same as `function(){}`. It is the same ``forEach`` just written shortly. You can refer the official Mozilla documentation for arrow functions.

Comment: Ah, thank you for explaining, I was wondering if this was supposed to convert the 2D array into 1D, and just realized that this was a proofing code, thank you.

Comment: @edmund To convert try `.flat()`

Comment: Hi TheMaster, thank you for the suggestion, it worked well ^^ thank you