# How to set values of array to the rows?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't understand how to set values of array to the target range of rows after `.map` in Google Sheets.

```js
function chekItNow() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const arrVals = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 7, 4).getValues();
  Logger.log(arrVals);
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    const nextVals = arrVals[i].map(x => x * 5);
    Logger.log(nextVals);
    let targetRange = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 7, 4);
    targetRange.setValues(nextVals);
  }
}
```

I'm new in JS. Unfortunately, can't find info about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map both the outer and inner arrays:

```
const rg = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 7, 4);
const arrVals = rg.getValues();
rg.setValues(arrVals.map(row => row.map(col => col*5)))
```

Also see [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445181/)

Answer (score 1):

[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues()) method expects a 2D array as parameter, in which the outer array dimension is for rows and the inner dimension for columns. Before setting the values, you first need to fill the `nextVals` array within the `for` loop with each row array, which are the ones you're getting from the `.map` function in each iteration. I tested the following code and worked successfully:

```
function chekItNow() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  const arrVals = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 7, 4).getValues();
  let nextVals=[];

  Logger.log(arrVals);
  for (let i = 0; i < arrVals.length; i++) {
    nextVals.push(arrVals[i].map(x => x * 5));
  }

  Logger.log(nextVals);
  let targetRange = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 7, 4);
  targetRange.setValues(nextVals);
}
```