# Using Google Sheets scripts, why does my if statement always return false when comparing cell values?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, boolean

I need to compare two cell values and act on them if they are different. My "if" statement always returns false when comparing the cell contents however, and I can't figure out why:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // apply to sheet name only 
  var testvalues = sheet.getRange('A1:A2').getValues(); // array of values to be tested
  var testvalue1 = testvalues[0]; // The contents from A1
  var testvalue2 = testvalues[1]; // The contents from A2
  var test1 = testvalue1 == testvalue2; // True False test
  var test2 = testvalue1 === testvalue2;// True False test
  Browser.msgBox(testvalue1 + " and " + testvalue2 + " being the same is " + test1 + " and " + test2); // Sentence revealing outcome
};
```

test1 and test2 always return false no matter what the contents of cell A1 and A2 are (empty, number, text, different). If I edit the testvalues to this:

```
  var testvalue1 = "We are the same value";
  var testvalue2 = "We are the same value";
```

or

```
  var testvalue1 = testvalues[0];
  var testvalue2 = testvalues[0];
```

then suddenly the tests both return True as expected. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing in this, it's infuriating? Currently in A1 and A2 is the value 1 (before I potentially get asked about that).

The end goal is to use a border to partition different cell contents. I have the rest of it working perfectly but I've isolated the problem to the above concept.

Comment: Is it comparing objects under the hood? What are the types of testvalue1 and testvalue2?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: `getValues()` always returns a 2D array: `[[A1],[A2]]`. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60445654/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Answer:

*The `.getValues()` method returns a 2-dimensional array, and so you aren't referencing the values within each cell correctly in your array.*

#### More Information:

Let's assume that both `A1` and `A2` contain the string `"THIS"`.
Running the following line:

```
var testvalues = sheet.getRange('A1:A2').getValues();
```

will assign the array `[[THIS], [THIS]]` to `testvalues`.

#### Code fix:

You need to change:

```
var testvalue1 = testvalues[0]; // The contents from A1
var testvalue2 = testvalues[1]; // The contents from A2
```

to:

```
var testvalue1 = testvalues[0][0]; // The contents from A1
var testvalue2 = testvalues[1][0]; // The contents from A2
```

#### References:

- [Class `Range` | Apps Script - Method `getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Answer (score 1):

The following line of code is incorrect, below it is corrected.

```
  var testvalue1 = testvalues[0][0]; // The contents from A1
  var testvalue2 = testvalues[1][0]; // The contents from A2
```

You are originally grabbing the entire row instead of a single cell.