# Google Script Help - Working with date array. Not getting correct result while comparing dates

Tags: arrays, date, google-apps-script

I wanted to compare the date and time in a column which the current date and time. if Date+time in column is future than it should log the array number (see code below)

But, Following script giving random answer.

```
function datecompare() {
   var fms = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('FMS');

  var now = new Date();

  var rangePl = fms.getRange(1,1,10);
  var valuePl = rangePl.getValues();

  for (var i=0; i<10; i++)
  { if (valuePl[i] > now) { Logger.log(i) ;}// This should log the when value is greater than current time
  }

}
```

Comment: Try ````valuePl[i][0]````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Google Sheets scripts, why does my if statement always return false when comparing cell values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61062937/using-google-sheets-scripts-why-does-my-if-statement-always-return-false-when-c)

Comment: @TheMaster It's a 1 dimension array

Comment: @Rishi If it was, I wouldn't have asked  you to try that. Check what `getValues()` returns in the  official documentation

Comment: @TheMaster, Amazing thanks a lot it works