# Searching for a value and if a value exists adding a row with copying the data in google spreadsheet

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, for-of-loop

I want to search for a word in a certain column and then if the value exists, I want to copy the row below with its values and change the word to two different words.
My issue was in getting the found word row Number to insert a row below it.

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fE404JUbw3aytlqtoht6FfrIhYhTpSe2MM5UDnBkFc4");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
let range = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = range.getValues();
var typeRange = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
var typeValues = typeRange.getValues();

  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= lastRow ; i++){
    for (let type of typeValues){
      if (type == "Both"){
        var bothRow = i+1;
        
      }
////      var bothRow = sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,typeValues[i].length);
////      ss.insertRowsAfter(bothRow, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

I have used alert to check and it inserted an infinite number of rows after row number 1.

```
function myFunction() {
  
  let sheetui= SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  sheetui.createMenu("Rahaf Game")
  .addItem("Stage 1", 'pop')
  .addToUi();
  
//  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fE404JUbw3aytlqtoht6FfrIhYhTpSe2MM5UDnBkFc4");
//  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
//  let range = sheet.getDataRange();
//  var values = range.getValues();
//  var typeRange = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
//  var typeValues = typeRange.getValues();
}
  function pop(){
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fE404JUbw3aytlqtoht6FfrIhYhTpSe2MM5UDnBkFc4");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
  var typeRange = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
  var typeValues = typeRange.getValues();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i <= lastRow ; i++){
    for (let type of typeValues){
      if (type == "Both"){
        var bothRow = i+1;
        ss.insertRowsAfter(bothRow, 1);
      }
////      var bothRow = sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,typeValues[i].length);
////      ss.insertRowsAfter(bothRow, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please help in achieving the required result in inserting a row below and copy the values into it with changing the word into two words?

Comment: What is the issue? What is happening in place of what should be happening? Any errors?

Comment: I have noticed that it is bot getting inside the if condition!

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*`.getValues()` returns a 2D array of values and you are referencing it as if it is unidimentional.*

#### Code fix:

You need to change your conditional such that the object you are checking is an array:

```
if (type == "Both"){
//code
}
```

Should be:

```
if (type == ["Both"]){
//code
}
```

#### Adding a row and copying the data to it:

You can add a row in a sheet after a given row with the `insertRowsAfter()` and use `.getRange().setValues()` to copy in the data:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= lastRow ; i++){
  for (let type of typeValues){
    if (type == ["Both"]){
      var bothRow = i + 1;
      ss.insertRowsAfter(bothRow, 1);
      // increment lastRow as there is now one more row in the sheet
      lastRow++;
      // increment i as you want to skip the row you just copied!
      i++;
      var rangeToCopy = sheet.getRange(bothRow + ':' + bothRow).getValues();
      sheet.getRange((bothRow + 1) + ':' + (bothRow + 1)).setValues(rangeToCopy);
    }
  }
}
```

Don't forget to increment `lastRow` by 1 if you add a new row so that your loop still reaches the end of the sheet.

#### References:

- [Class `Range` | Apps Script - Method `getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

#### Related Questions:

- [Using Google Sheets scripts, why does my if statement always return false when comparing cell values?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61063808/11551468)

Comment: this worked for me, can you also advise regarding copying data to the last row of the rows matching the condition?

Comment: Why isn't `ss.insertRowsAfter(bothRow, 1)` suitable? Also if you're only inserting one row then `ss.insertRowAfter(bothRow)` should be enough.

Comment: You do need to add 1 to lastRow whenever you insert however else your loop won't reach the end of the sheet.

Comment: but I want to copy the data of the row that meets the condition and paste it into the new row.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this, glad to be able to help!

Comment: I have tried the above edited code and got this Error Message: (Exception: Range not found (line 26, file "bothCondition"))

Comment: Which line is line 26?

Comment: var rangeToCopy = ss.getRange(bothRow + ':' + bothRow).getValues();

Comment: Ahh sorry - the `.getRange()` should be of `sheet`, not `ss`. Updated my code.

Comment: Can you log the value of bothRow before the line and check it's value?

Comment: I got this: Exception: Bad value (line 26, file "bothCondition")

Comment: Have you assigned i with var in the for loop? var i = 0 rather than just i = 0?

Comment: Please can you share your sheet then; this is hard to debug without it